# Payment Gateway returns Error HTTP Status - 400

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, mastercard

I’m trying to redirect my MVC project to pay migs payment Gateway.
Here’s the URL generated by my code.  (For security reasons i have changed the value with the word “value” )

**https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?vpc_AccessCode=value&vpc_Amount=100&vpc_Command=pay&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_Merchant=TESTvalue&vpc_MerchTxnRef=value160426&vpc_OrderInfo=value&vpc_ReturnURL=http%3a%2f%2fgoogle.com&vpc_Version=1&vpc_SecureHash=6d84a03c6c41f06e945f618657b4a93a**

I would like to know if there’s an error in this generated URL. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how are you creating your hash code ?

Answer (score 0):

@Derpuku Der - I have uploaded an example of a MIGS payment gateway written in Asp.Net MVC for you. All you need to do is add your MIGS info to the web.config file & publish it to a live domain.
https://github.com/mwd-au/MIGS-payment-gateway-MVC5

Answer (score 0):

I guess the cause of the problem is that you encode the `ReturnUrl`, which would affect your hash result and lead to an incorrect one.